# Assigning user project access via Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to create a new project via Terraform and then assign a user the editor role to that project with the below code.  However the user is not getting provisioned and my service account is instead getting locked out.  I have had similar issue with `google_project_iam_member`

```
resource "google_project" "sandbox_project" {
  name            = var.project_name
  project_id      = var.project_id
  org_id          = "XXXXX"
}

resource "google_project_iam_binding" "project" {
  project         = var.project_id
  role            = "roles/editor"
  members          = ["user:${var.user_email}",]
}
```

However if I run the command:
`gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding test-project --member='user:test@org.com' --role='roles/editor'`
The policy get assigned appropriately.

What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: What does Terraform say after `terraform apply`?

Comment: ```$ terraform apply -input=false "tfplan"
google_project_iam_binding.project: Creating...
google_project_iam_binding.project: Creation complete after 8s [id=test-project/roles/editor]```
Above is for after the project was already created thus why that resource is not listed
When using iam_member:
```$ terraform apply -input=false "tfplan"
google_project_iam_member.project: Creating...
google_project_iam_member.project: Creation complete after 8s [id=test-project/roles/editor/user:test@org.com]```